# Maven modules are trying to use parent dependencies

Tags: maven, module, scope, dependencies, system

I have a maven project where the parent module has a lib directory containing various jars that are necessary for compilation, but aren't included in the final product. When I try to get the children modules to build it fails. It says "The following artifacts could not be resolved" then eventually says "Could not find artifact local_dependency at C:\path\to\project\modules\module_name\lib\local_dependency.jar".

The children modules do not depend on the libraries that the parent uses, however it still wants to include them. Is there an option I need to set to prevent this?

Parent Pom snippet:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <currentVersion>1.0.0</currentVersion>
</properties>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project_artifact</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${currentVersion}</version>

<modules>
    <module>modules/module_name</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>local_dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/local_dependency.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Child pom snippet:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${currentVersion}</version>
    <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.some.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact_name</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId> <!-- The child depends on the parent for the parent's API-->
        <artifactId>project_artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${currentVersion}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </depdencency>
</dependencies>
```

So from this, the child pom will attempt to include group.id:local_dependency from project_base/modules/module_name/lib/local_dependency.jar but it doesn't exist and doesn't need to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child inherits the parent's dependencies, whether or not you include the dependency explicitly. Two possible ways to resolve the issue are:

- Don't build any jar artifact in the parent - create a sub-module for this and use the sub-module as a dependency in its siblings.
- Use a fixed path (not relative to ${basedir}, since this changes in each module build, which tries to resolve the location anew). If you always build from the parent's directory, you could use ${user.dir}.

Comment: I took your first option, I moved the parent over to it's own module and everything is working great now.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude specific transitive dependencies in the dependency declaration. In your case, the following change in the child pom's dependency on the parent should get the build working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId> <!-- The child depends on the parent for the parent's API-->
    <artifactId>project_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${currentVersion}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>local_dependency</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Now I look more closely, I realise that the dependency from child to parent is not the cause of the problem. The child will inherit the parent's dependencies due to the project structure, whether or not an explicit dependency is declared, and this is why neither the optional element nor the specific transitive exclusion works. I'll add another (better) answer...